# Update soap request (node value and attribute value) using groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I try to update soap message using groovy. Node value can update using following script. someone help me to update attribute value.

**XML:**

```
<TITLE>Computer Parts</TITLE>
<PART Price="High">
   <ITEM>Motherboard</ITEM>
   <MANUFACTURER>ASUS</MANUFACTURER>
   <MODEL>P3B-F</MODEL>
   <COST> 123.00</COST>
</PART>
```

**Update Node**
`xpath = //*:PART/*:COST/`

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "SOAP_MSG#Request" )

holder.setNodeValue( xpath, "200" )

holder.updateProperty()
```

**Update Attribute**
`xpath = //*:PART/@Price`

How to update the Price attribute?

Comment: Please check the solution and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script, and find comments inline:

```
//Pass xml string to parseText method
def pxml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

//Have the expected new cost
def expectedCost = 200.00

//Have the expected new price
def expectedPrice = 'Low'

//Get the cost node
def cost = pxml.'**'.find{it.name() == 'COST'}

//Replace the value with expected value
cost.replaceBody(expectedCost)

//Get the cost node
def part = pxml.'**'.find{it.name() == 'PART'}

//Replace the value with expected value
part.@Price = expectedPrice

//Print the updated xml; use log.info if using in soapui
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(pxml)
```

Online <kbd>[Demo](http://ideone.com/qMBRuy)</kbd>